# issue in creating id in layout android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I created a package name and done by creating all files past month. Later I changed package name in manifest. Now if i create a layout for eg: id for textview. It's not referring to id and in gen folder also not creating. Then I restart eclipse and checked, still problem occurs. Cleaned the project, still I am not able to access id(tvnames) of textview that not displaying. Please help me to solve this strange issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do any xml files have errors?

Comment: no @TimCastelijns i just changed the package name of folders and manifest package and created xml and java file. but that id is not accessing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you imported the right R file in your class? You might have imported "android.R" and not "com.yourapp.R."